# Эквивалентен ли вызов обычного оператора new вызову функции allocate стандартного аллокатора +placement new?

Tags: c++, память, c++17, c++20

Эквивалентен ли вызов обычного оператора new вызову функции allocate стандартного аллокатора +placement new? Т.е меня интересует, не будет ли

```
std::allocator<int> alloc;
int* test = alloc.allocate(1)
test = new(test) int(5)
```

менее эффективно, нежали

```
int* test = new int(5)
```

Будет ли память так же аллоцировтаься блоками, или в случае использования аллокатора в ручную,  `alloc.allocate(1)` будет восприниматься как аллоцировтаь только 4 байта? Так же меня интересует, будет ли вызова deallocate + ручной вызов деструктора эквивалентен вызову оператора delete?

Comment: Надо же, какой сложный язык С++, 2 недели вопрос висит и никто не знает ответа на него...